# Allowing users to only enter specific tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making an app where I need users to input description using a wysiwyg editor. I cannot trust user input, so I need to only allow `a`, `em`, `ul`, `li` tags. How do I strip the others easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/

Answer (score 4):

Rails has some sanitizing methods baked in. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

These are view helpers, so if you want to sanitize before saving the user input you'll need to include the helpers somewhere useful.